# How do I set compression to "none" for all of the tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to set the `DataCompressionOptions` to `None` for all of the tables in a database.

I can run

```
USE [MyDatabase]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tablex] 
REBUILD PARTITION = ALL
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
```

And it works fine but I need to set this for about 50 tables.

Comment: `SELECT 'ALTER TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' REBUILD ...;' FROM sys.tables WHERE schema_id = 1;`

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you for responding. I ran the query and it executed successfully but when I went to check the compression it was still set to "Page"

Comment: running this query will only create the script for you, you need to copy paste the script and execute that or use a cursor to do it for your as I have shown in my answer

Comment: That's because this just generates the commands for you. You need to copy them, paste them into a new query window, and run them.

Answer (score 2):

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @cur CURSOR;

SET @Cur = CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name)+ '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) 
        + ' REBUILD PARTITION = ALL  WITH  (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE )'
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s  ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id 

OPEN @cur

FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @Sql 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql 

   FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @Sql 
END

CLOSE @cur
DEALLOCATE @cur
```

Comment: This worked great.  Thank you to both Aaron and M. Ali.

Comment: An arcane error forced me to decompress every single compressed object in 3 TFS databases to migrate them. This answer proved to be indispensable. Also see the queries at https://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2016/11/07/Downgrade-SQL-Server-database-from-Enterprise-to-Standard-Edition.aspx which also allow you to decompress indexes. It was cited at https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/revert-the-data-compression-on-the-sql-database This query was also useful in identifying compressed objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988326/query-all-table-data-and-index-compression

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.'
              + QUOTENAME(t.name)
              + ' REBUILD PARTITION = ALL  WITH  (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE )'
              + char(10) + char(13)
FROM   sys.tables t
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
               ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE  T.NAME IN ( '<table_list>' )

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- tables

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)'

GO

-- indexes

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)'

GO
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought the code was readable enough not to be described. Important - in my code tables and indexes are decompressed (people usually forget about indexes). The "sp_MSforeachtable" Stored Procedure comes with SQL Server, but it is not documented. The Stored Procedure "sp_MSforeachtable" allows us to easily process some code against each and every table in a single database.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/undocumented-sp_msforeachtable-procedure-in-sql-server/