# How to remove SQL compression ffrom all of the tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, compression

I need to change SQL edition from developer to standard. Unfortunately, there are many tables with enabled compression.

I tried to use query from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759459/how-do-i-set-compression-to-none-for-all-of-the-tables-in-a-sql-server-databas/64702261?noredirect=1#comment114402209_64702261) but when I trying to run this query I getting error in line `QUOTENAME (s.NAME)` and `QUOTENAME(t.name)` which says:

> The multi part identifier "s.name" could not be found.

What I am doing wrong?

[EDIT]

By my mistake I had an error with the query and now I was able to run it. Command output was successful but in messages I see 0 rows affected.
I checked again selected DB by running this query

`select feature_name from sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features`

and still in SQL output I see no changes. Compression is still ON.

Comment: Show us your attempt so we can help you; we can't tell you what you did wrong if you don't show that attempt. The linked answer looks like it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably unnecessary.  Table and Index Compression is supported by every edition of SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SQL/SQL-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Ok but still when will make upgrade from Dev ed. to standard, 3 databases are in "suspect" state due to message like this "DAtabase 'SP_Search_CrawlStore' cannot be started in this edition of SQL Server because part or all of object 'MSSCrawlHostsLog' is enabled with data compression or vardecimal storage format. Data compression and verdecimal storage format are only supported on SQL Enterprise edition"

Comment: What version of SQL Server Standard Edition?

Comment: 13.0.1601.5 - so it's 2016

Comment: That's RTM and it's out of support.  Try SQL Server 2016 SP2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052908/kb4052908-sql-server-2016-service-pack-2-release-information

Comment: I upgraded succesfully to SP2 (13.0.5026.0) but this does not changed anything.
Below query showed 41 afftected tables in total in 1 DB

SELECT st.name, st.object_id, sp.partition_id, sp.partition_number, sp.data_compression,
sp.data_compression_desc FROM sys.partitions SP
INNER JOIN sys.tables ST ON
st.object_id = sp.object_id
WHERE data_compression <> 0

Sample result for 1 table was as below:
Name: MSSCrawl, Object_id=958485746, partition_id=58686858585885, partinion_number=1,data_compression=2, data_compression_desc=PAGE

Comment: But can you restore/attach the database?

Comment: Everything is fine now, I mean after I did SP2 upgrade I did not restarted server. So right after I did this , I run again downgrade from developer ed. to standard and all was OK. Thanks a lot for support :)